# Exercise Sheets of a course based on Hovey's Model Categories book

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, model-categories

I am not entirely sure this type of question belongs here, but I'll try.

I am preparing for an exam based on Hovey's book 'Model Categories'. The book is light on exercises, so I have been wondering if somebody could maybe point me to the exercise sheets of a course in model categories, idealy based on the same book.
I am quite familiar with the model structure on chain complexes, I know some basic algebraic topology, but structured exercises helping me understand the contents of the book would seem to be very useful for me.